# Image scaling trouble in FancyBox2

Tags: fancybox

I have two problems related to image presentation in FancyBox2:

- Images are automatically applied zoom to. Ideally this should only happen when the user clicks on an image.
- The box holding the image does not fit.

The zooming problem is only present in IE and Chrome (not in Opera and Firefox), while the other problem is present in all browsers. [This image illustrates the problems in chrome.](http://i42.tinypic.com/10ogzmb.png)

I have tried various configuration parameters in FancyBox, without luck. Right now I simply use:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({'type' : 'iframe'});
```

Any clues to why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `type: 'image'` for images. `Iframe` type is for external html pages.

Images are displayed either re-sized to fit into the viewport (when `fitToView` is set to `true`) or in their original size (when `fitToView` is set to `false`). If the image is bigger than the view port, then you have to scroll down the parent page to view the whole image.

You may use the `buttons` helper to toggle an image from its scaled size to its real size too.